# Does it make sense to unit test for a not existing Id

Tags: c#, unit-testing, integration-testing

Does it make sense to pass a not existing unique Id to my `GetXX` method to expect a created list without any count? I mean, when I test for an existing Id the List is created independent of the number of items it holds. Why should the list be `null` or have no `count == 0` if I pass a not existing id? I am not sure about the sense of this test.

```
[Test]
public void Get_Teststeps_By_UnitId_Not_Existing()
{
    // ARRANGE
    ITeststepDataProvider provider = new TeststepDataProvider(_connectionString);
    int unitId = 100;

    // ACT
    List<Teststep> units = provider.GetTeststepsByUnitId(unitId);

    // ASSERT
    Assert.IsNotNull(units);
    Assert.Count(0, units);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will very much depend on the system under test, what is it supposed to do and how is it defined. For example if you defined that the method that you are testing should never return null values but empty collections for some given input (such as non existing ids - whatever that means) then it makes perfect sense to test this case and the correct behavior of the method.

Answer (score 1):

I think the negative test is a valid one to execute.  Whether it should have a count of 0 and not be null I guess is up to what the application is trying accomplish.  As a rule, though, you want to test the negative cases as much as the positive ones.

Answer (score 1):

The unit test isn't *only* to verify the GetXX method as it is now (although it never hurts to test that the method does what you think it does even if it's simple), it also keeps anyone changing/refactoring the code later from accidentally changing something that makes your other code break. If you depend on a certain behavior, you should always make sure to make a test for it, no matter how simplistic.

In other words, don't just skip a test because it doesn't make sense right now, think about later maintenance and that the test actually makes for good documentation for users of the method on how the method is *supposed* to be used and/or not used.

Answer (score 1):

If your code calling always expects `GetXX()` to return an instance of a `List` then you should have a test for it. This will ensure that someone can't change the `GetXX()` code and have it return `null` and then cause `NullReferenceException`s in your system.